# orientation changes, when are all my view controllers rotated?

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation

If I have several UIViewControllers pushed onto my navigation stack, how/when are the none-visible (bottom) view controllers re-layed-out? Do they all get layed-out at the same time as the visible view controller, or only once they are popped onto the display stack?

**edit:**
I currently manage resizing subviews myself (rather than setting autoresizing=YES). I do my resizing in the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method, so that it is all animated nicely. I'm guessing this method doesn't get called for any uiviewcontroller not on top of the display stack. So is there a built-in way to know if the current uiviewcontroller is the one being displayed, and if it isn't, which method should I override to relayout my subviews for the uiviewcontrollers that aren't at the top of the display stack?

Thanks!

Sunny

Comment: I suppose it happens by default. Assuming you have drilled down 5 levels tossing one viewController over another on the navigation stack. At level 5 if you change device orientation. It re-lays-out the top viewController. Now in this orientation if you start moving back to level4->level3 onwards, I assume the re-laying out is done automatically. Is it not the case with you? If not we can workout a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the orientation in `viewWillAppear`.  If you check the orientation here, you can be assured that a view will always appear with the correct layout for a given orientation.  You still need to rotate it in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` though.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        [self layoutForPortrait];    
    }

    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        [self layoutForLandscape];                
    }
}
```